# Eclipse not seeing configs inside a folder inside src

Tags: eclipse, spring, config

I have an Eclipse project with some 50 different config files that currently reside directly under the src folder. I want to put them all in one folder, for example src/config so it's less cluttered.

But Eclipse doesn't seem to like it. Following advice from around here, I tried configuring the Build Path to include this folder, and the Run Configurations as well, but no luck.

What to do? Leave them all in the src folder?

Comment: What type of config files are you talking about?

Comment: Spring configs, and others.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the package manager pane in eclipse?